# How to unit test service where you have to pass bean that class is of accessibility scope? [Spock]

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I tried to use a hexagonal approach wherein my domain package I have classes with view scope.

But there I faced a problem, how to mock something that I can't use because of view access.

I should @Autowire that beans but so on I realized I still can't use and pass some of them as mock's and rest as autowired bean's.

I don't think so that it is a good solution to change an access view to do tests.

So I looking to a solution how to do it in proper way. Any ideas?

Below is my example:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RecipeService {

private final RecipeRepository recipeRepository; //view scope access
private final UserService userService; //public access

public Optional<Recipe> getRecipeById(Long id) {
        return recipeRepository.findById(id);
}

///////////////
@Repository
interface RecipeRepository extends JpaRepository<Recipe, Long> {
Optional<Recipe> findById(Long recipeId);
}
```

And test:

```
class RecipeServiceTest extends Specification {

private RecipeRepository recipeRepository = Mock()
private UserService userService = Mock()

void setup() {
        recipeService = new RecipeService(recipeRepository, userService)
}
```

In that way I received error : `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class .recipe.domain.RecipeRepository from class .recipe.service.RecipeServiceTest`

**[EDITED]**

Below tree

```
└───src
    ├───main
    │   ├───java
    │   │   └───com
    │   │       └───app
    │   │           └───example
    │   │               │   
    │   │               ├───recipe
    │   │               │   ├───controller
    │   │               │   └───domain
    │   │               │           RecipeRepository.java // visible scope
    │   │               │           RecipeService.java // visible public
    └───test
        ├───groovy
        │   └───com
        │       └───app
        │           └───example
        │               ├───recipe
        │               │   ├───controller
        │               │   └───domain
        │               │           RecipeServiceTest.groovy
```

Comment: Assuming that `RecipeServiceTest` is in the same package as `RecipeService` and given the fact that `RecipeService` has a `RecipeRepository` field, I assume that the class is visible from there. But then it would also be visible from the test. Your question does not provide any package names and insufficient information in general. Please edit it and make it an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because I don't like to guess or speculate. Hexagonal architecture, if done right, should make testing easier, not harder. So I need to see the code in order to be able to say more.

Comment: ok I added tree

Comment: Wouldn't a project on GitHub have been easier than producing this ASCII art? And why do you use a package-scoped interface at all? Why not make the interface public? Anyway, I take a look tomorrow and see if I can reproduce your problem. The GitHub project would still be much preferred, I would have less work and could reproduce the problem more quickly and easily.

Comment: I copied your code incl. package names, generated the missing `User*` classes as dummies myself, activated Lombok, added the missing `private RecipeService recipeService` declaration in your test (you cannot initialise something that was not declared) and ran a dummy test without any problems. With your incoherent set of code snippets I cannot reproduce the problem. So as I said, give me an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This question is not one. Try for yourself: Create a new project, copy only what is here and try to compile and run it. You will fail. Ergo: no MCVE.

Comment: And please define what you mean by "view access". I have no idea what you are talking about. Your code does not explain it either.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you for trying to help me. I think I identify a problem. The test tree was different ( last name of package in test I named *service* not *domain*) then when I paste it here I make a correct proper name, but I didn't realize it can be that problem. Now when both `RecipeService` and `RecipeServiceTest` are in the same package scope and both have visibility to `RecipeRepository`. I think the problem is solved. And BTW answering on your question about interface not public. I think that is the proper way in hexagonal approach to make it closed and only services should be public.

Comment: See? This is why I asked for an MCVE and not ASCII art directory tree. ;-) The positive thing about MCVE is that while trying to reduce your problem to the minimum, you usually learn more about the problem itself. Often that already is enough to identify the root cause, like in your case. Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass recipeRepository(as well as userService) as a parameter into to RecipeService, so RecipeService and RecipeRepository will not be tightly coupled. Then you can mock recipeRepository

```
public class RecipeService (RecipeRepository recipeRepository,UserService userService) {   
public Optional<Recipe> getRecipeById(Long id) {
        return recipeRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Comment: As I understand you well, the lombok annotation `@RequiredArgsConstructor` do the constructor you had written.